# Name of mathematician who made an error, which made his later work useless?

Tags: mathematicians

In school, many years ago, my teacher taught me about a mathematician who was working on developing tables (or something similar to that).  He apparently worked for years and then made a single mistake in his calculations.  Consequently, the remaining work he did on these tables, which spanned additional years, was inaccurate.  I tried looking him up recently but can't find any information in a general search of the internet.  Does anyone know who this mathematician was?

Comment: This sounds like the computation of $\pi$ by William Shanks to $707$ places, but there was a mistake that resulted in only the first $527$ being correct.  That nevertheless was the record number of digits at the time.  See the [Chronology of computation of $\pi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_computation_of_%CF%80) for more details.  Actually several previous attempts turned out to be similarly flawed.

Comment: I wonder where that Wikipedia page's figure "Took 15 years to calculate" comes from - it's not in the cited "The Quest for Pi" article

Comment: @Dap: [His St. Andrews biography](http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~history/Biographies/Shanks.html) has some surrounding details, esp. concerning his collaboration with [William Rutherford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Rutherford_(mathematician)).

Comment: I hope that neither your teacher nor you are planning to use this story to scoff: Shanks's error in calculating the decimal expansion of $\pi$ led to more errors in the same calculation. It did not make all his later mathematical work useless.

Answer (score 0):

[William Shanks](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Shanks.html) is probably who they meant